# Insertion of weighted point with info in CGAL regular triangulation

Tags: c++, insert, triangulation, cgal, weighted

I'm facing a problem that I hope some others have faced before because I can't find a way out !

I have a regular triangulation in CGAL in which I wish to insert some weighted points with info `std::pair<myweightpoint, myinfo>` one by one and to get the handle to the vertex (`Vertex_handle`) once it is inserted ! The thing is that there is no such function. It exists several functions to insert :

- `Vertex_handle`[`Regular_triangulation::insert`](http://doc.cgal.org/latest/Triangulation_2/classCGAL_1_1Regular__triangulation__2.html#af7c85fa190b96836fb6c6a8704a0171c)`( const Weighted_point & p ) ;`

That returns a `Vertex_handle` which is cool but does not take weighted points WITH INFO which is very important for me and what I do with those vertices.

- `std::ptrdiff_t`[`Regular_triangulation::insert`](http://doc.cgal.org/latest/Triangulation_2/classCGAL_1_1Regular__triangulation__2.html#a6cf16173eb2b2fa3c37e643650f27e33)`( WeightedPointWithInfoInputIterator first, WeightedPointWithInfoInputIterator last ) ;`

Which allows me to insert some weighted points with info (which is good) but doesn't gives me a handle to the inserted vertex. Moreover, since I am inserting points one at a time, for now I'm doing things like this :

```
v_wpoints.resize(1) ;
v_wpoints[0] = std::make_pair(myweightpoint, myinfo) ;
rt.insert(v_wpoints.begin(), v_wpoints.end()) ;
```

which seems really dirty. So, my questions are : why isn't there a function like that :

`Vertex_handle Regular_triangulation::insert( const Weighted_point_with_info & p ) ;`

and how can I do to insert a weighted point with info in the regular triangulation and get the handle to the vertex inserted.

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you can do is:

```
Vertex_handle v = rt.insert(wp);
v->info()=the_info;
```

Comment: Perfect ! Just perfect ! <3