# Insert range of points with info in CGAL Voronoi diagram

Tags: c++, cgal, voronoi

In an [earlier question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/42033698), I asked how to associate non-geometric information (e.g. weights) with sites when constructing a Voronoi diagram in CGAL. 

 My solution involved `#include-ing CGAL/Triangulation_vertex_base_with_info_2.h` and used a loop of the form:

```
std::ifstream ifs("data/data1.dt.cin");  // Input file for points
VoronoiDiagram vd;                     // CGAL Voronoi diagram data structure
Site t;
int ctr=0;
while ( ifs >> t ) {                  // Read a site from the file...
    Face_handle fh = vd.insert(t);     // ...add the site...
    fh->dual()->info() = ctr++;       // ...and attach some info to it
}
```

The loop was inspired by the answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/29748559). But it has a major drawback. Points are added to the Voronoi diagram one at a time, which is very slow. It is much faster to insert a range of points all at once.

The CGAL documentation gives examples of how to do this [here](http://doc.cgal.org/latest/Triangulation_2/index.html#Triangulation_2SettingInformationWhileInserting) in the context of Delaunay triangulations, but those solutions don't seem to work with Voronoi diagrams. For example, here is my attempt to use a boost zip iterator, as suggested in the CGAL example [`Triangulation_2/info_insert_with_zip_iterator_2.cpp`](http://doc.cgal.org/latest/Triangulation_2/Triangulation_2_2info_insert_with_zip_iterator_2_8cpp-example.html). My example is a minor modification of the CGAL example code [`Voronoi_diagram_2/vd_2_point_location.cpp`](http://doc.cgal.org/latest/Voronoi_diagram_2/Voronoi_diagram_2_2vd_2_point_location_8cpp-example.html)

```
// standard includes
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <cassert>
#include <list>
#include <boost/iterator/zip_iterator.hpp>
// includes for defining the Voronoi diagram adaptor
#include <CGAL/Exact_predicates_inexact_constructions_kernel.h>
#include <CGAL/Delaunay_triangulation_2.h>
#include <CGAL/Triangulation_vertex_base_with_info_2.h>
#include <CGAL/Voronoi_diagram_2.h>
#include <CGAL/Delaunay_triangulation_adaptation_traits_2.h>
#include <CGAL/Delaunay_triangulation_adaptation_policies_2.h>
// typedefs for defining the adaptor
typedef CGAL::Exact_predicates_inexact_constructions_kernel                  K;
typedef CGAL::Triangulation_vertex_base_with_info_2<int, K>                  VB;
typedef CGAL::Triangulation_data_structure_2<VB>                             TDS;
typedef CGAL::Delaunay_triangulation_2<K,TDS>                                DT;
typedef CGAL::Delaunay_triangulation_adaptation_traits_2<DT>                 AT;
typedef CGAL::Delaunay_triangulation_caching_degeneracy_removal_policy_2<DT> AP;
typedef CGAL::Voronoi_diagram_2<DT,AT,AP>                                    VD;
// typedef for the result type of the point location
typedef AT::Site_2                    Site_2;
typedef AT::Point_2                   Point_2;
typedef VD::Locate_result             Locate_result;
typedef VD::Vertex_handle             Vertex_handle;
typedef VD::Face_handle               Face_handle;
typedef VD::Halfedge_handle           Halfedge_handle;
typedef VD::Ccb_halfedge_circulator   Ccb_halfedge_circulator;
int main()
{
  std::ifstream ifs("data/data1.dt.cin");
  VD vd;
  Site_2 t;
  std::list<Site_2> sites;
  std::list<int>    site_info;
  int ctr=0;
  while ( ifs >> t ) { 
      sites.push_back(t);         // Add the site...
      site_info.push_back(ctr++); // ...attach some info to it
  }
  ifs.close();
  vd.insert(
      boost::make_zip_iterator(boost::make_tuple(sites.begin(), 
                                                 site_info.begin())),
      boost::make_zip_iterator(boost::make_tuple(sites.end(), 
                                                 site_info.end())));
  return 0;
}
```

This code fails to compile, with the error coming from the line with the `boost::make_zip_iterator()`.  Here is the error from g++:

```
In file included from vdtst3.cxx:11:0:
/usr/local/include/CGAL/Voronoi_diagram_2.h: In instantiation of ‘CGAL::Voronoi_diagram_2<DG, AT, AP>::size_type CGAL::Voronoi_diagram_2<DG, AT, AP>::insert(Iterator, Iterator) [with Iterator = boost::zip_iterator<boost::tuples::tuple<std::_List_iterator<CGAL::Point_2<CGAL::Epick> >, std::_List_iterator<int>, boost::tuples::null_type, boost::tuples::null_type, boost::tuples::null_type, boost::tuples::null_type, boost::tuples::null_type, boost::tuples::null_type, boost::tuples::null_type, boost::tuples::null_type> >; DG = CGAL::Delaunay_triangulation_2<CGAL::Epick, CGAL::Triangulation_data_structure_2<CGAL::Triangulation_vertex_base_with_info_2<int, CGAL::Epick> > >; AT = CGAL::Delaunay_triangulation_adaptation_traits_2<CGAL::Delaunay_triangulation_2<CGAL::Epick, CGAL::Triangulation_data_structure_2<CGAL::Triangulation_vertex_base_with_info_2<int, CGAL::Epick> > > >; AP = CGAL::Delaunay_triangulation_caching_degeneracy_removal_policy_2<CGAL::Delaunay_triangulation_2<CGAL::Epick, CGAL::Triangulation_data_structure_2<CGAL::Triangulation_vertex_base_with_info_2<int, CGAL::Epick> > > >; CGAL::Voronoi_diagram_2<DG, AT, AP>::size_type = long unsigned int]’:
vdtst3.cxx:47:71:   required from here
/usr/local/include/CGAL/Voronoi_diagram_2.h:769:17: error: no matching function for call to ‘CGAL::Voronoi_diagram_2<CGAL::Delaunay_triangulation_2<CGAL::Epick, CGAL::Triangulation_data_structure_2<CGAL::Triangulation_vertex_base_with_info_2<int, CGAL::Epick> > >, CGAL::Delaunay_triangulation_adaptation_traits_2<CGAL::Delaunay_triangulation_2<CGAL::Epick, CGAL::Triangulation_data_structure_2<CGAL::Triangulation_vertex_base_with_info_2<int, CGAL::Epick> > > >, CGAL::Delaunay_triangulation_caching_degeneracy_removal_policy_2<CGAL::Delaunay_triangulation_2<CGAL::Epick, CGAL::Triangulation_data_structure_2<CGAL::Triangulation_vertex_base_with_info_2<int, CGAL::Epick> > > > >::insert(boost::iterator_facade<boost::zip_iterator<boost::tuples::tuple<std::_List_iterator<CGAL::Point_2<CGAL::Epick> >, std::_List_iterator<int>, boost::tuples::null_type, boost::tuples::null_type, boost::tuples::null_type, boost::tuples::null_type, boost::tuples::null_type, boost::tuples::null_type, boost::tuples::null_type, boost::tuples::null_type> >, boost::tuples::cons<CGAL::Point_2<CGAL::Epick>&, boost::tuples::cons<int&, boost::tuples::null_type> >, boost::bidirectional_traversal_tag, boost::tuples::cons<CGAL::Point_2<CGAL::Epick>&, boost::tuples::cons<int&, boost::tuples::null_type> >, long int>::reference)’
       insert(*it);
                 ^
/usr/local/include/CGAL/Voronoi_diagram_2.h:769:17: note: candidates are:
/usr/local/include/CGAL/Voronoi_diagram_2.h:744:22: note: CGAL::Voronoi_diagram_2<DG, AT, AP>::Face_handle CGAL::Voronoi_diagram_2<DG, AT, AP>::insert(const Site_2&, const Tag_true&) [with DG = CGAL::Delaunay_triangulation_2<CGAL::Epick, CGAL::Triangulation_data_structure_2<CGAL::Triangulation_vertex_base_with_info_2<int, CGAL::Epick> > >; AT = CGAL::Delaunay_triangulation_adaptation_traits_2<CGAL::Delaunay_triangulation_2<CGAL::Epick, CGAL::Triangulation_data_structure_2<CGAL::Triangulation_vertex_base_with_info_2<int, CGAL::Epick> > > >; AP = CGAL::Delaunay_triangulation_caching_degeneracy_removal_policy_2<CGAL::Delaunay_triangulation_2<CGAL::Epick, CGAL::Triangulation_data_structure_2<CGAL::Triangulation_vertex_base_with_info_2<int, CGAL::Epick> > > >; CGAL::Voronoi_diagram_2<DG, AT, AP>::Face_handle = CGAL::VoronoiDiagram_2::Internal::Handle_adaptor<CGAL::VoronoiDiagram_2::Internal::Face<CGAL::Voronoi_diagram_2<CGAL::Delaunay_triangulation_2<CGAL::Epick, CGAL::Triangulation_data_structure_2<CGAL::Triangulation_vertex_base_with_info_2<int, CGAL::Epick> > >, CGAL::Delaunay_triangulation_adaptation_traits_2<CGAL::Delaunay_triangulation_2<CGAL::Epick, CGAL::Triangulation_data_structure_2<CGAL::Triangulation_vertex_base_with_info_2<int, CGAL::Epick> > > >, CGAL::Delaunay_triangulation_caching_degeneracy_removal_policy_2<CGAL::Delaunay_triangulation_2<CGAL::Epick, CGAL::Triangulation_data_structure_2<CGAL::Triangulation_vertex_base_with_info_2<int, CGAL::Epick> > > > > > >; CGAL::Voronoi_diagram_2<DG, AT, AP>::Site_2 = CGAL::Point_2<CGAL::Epick>; CGAL::Tag_true = CGAL::Boolean_tag<true>]
   inline Face_handle insert(const Site_2& t, const Tag_true&) {
                      ^
/usr/local/include/CGAL/Voronoi_diagram_2.h:744:22: note:   candidate expects 2 arguments, 1 provided
/usr/local/include/CGAL/Voronoi_diagram_2.h:751:22: note: CGAL::Voronoi_diagram_2<DG, AT, AP>::Face_handle CGAL::Voronoi_diagram_2<DG, AT, AP>::insert(const Site_2&, const Tag_false&) [with DG = CGAL::Delaunay_triangulation_2<CGAL::Epick, CGAL::Triangulation_data_structure_2<CGAL::Triangulation_vertex_base_with_info_2<int, CGAL::Epick> > >; AT = CGAL::Delaunay_triangulation_adaptation_traits_2<CGAL::Delaunay_triangulation_2<CGAL::Epick, CGAL::Triangulation_data_structure_2<CGAL::Triangulation_vertex_base_with_info_2<int, CGAL::Epick> > > >; AP = CGAL::Delaunay_triangulation_caching_degeneracy_removal_policy_2<CGAL::Delaunay_triangulation_2<CGAL::Epick, CGAL::Triangulation_data_structure_2<CGAL::Triangulation_vertex_base_with_info_2<int, CGAL::Epick> > > >; CGAL::Voronoi_diagram_2<DG, AT, AP>::Face_handle = CGAL::VoronoiDiagram_2::Internal::Handle_adaptor<CGAL::VoronoiDiagram_2::Internal::Face<CGAL::Voronoi_diagram_2<CGAL::Delaunay_triangulation_2<CGAL::Epick, CGAL::Triangulation_data_structure_2<CGAL::Triangulation_vertex_base_with_info_2<int, CGAL::Epick> > >, CGAL::Delaunay_triangulation_adaptation_traits_2<CGAL::Delaunay_triangulation_2<CGAL::Epick, CGAL::Triangulation_data_structure_2<CGAL::Triangulation_vertex_base_with_info_2<int, CGAL::Epick> > > >, CGAL::Delaunay_triangulation_caching_degeneracy_removal_policy_2<CGAL::Delaunay_triangulation_2<CGAL::Epick, CGAL::Triangulation_data_structure_2<CGAL::Triangulation_vertex_base_with_info_2<int, CGAL::Epick> > > > > > >; CGAL::Voronoi_diagram_2<DG, AT, AP>::Site_2 = CGAL::Point_2<CGAL::Epick>; CGAL::Tag_false = CGAL::Boolean_tag<false>]
   inline Face_handle insert(const Site_2& t, const Tag_false&) {
                      ^
/usr/local/include/CGAL/Voronoi_diagram_2.h:751:22: note:   candidate expects 2 arguments, 1 provided
/usr/local/include/CGAL/Voronoi_diagram_2.h:757:22: note: CGAL::Voronoi_diagram_2<DG, AT, AP>::Face_handle CGAL::Voronoi_diagram_2<DG, AT, AP>::insert(const Site_2&) [with DG = CGAL::Delaunay_triangulation_2<CGAL::Epick, CGAL::Triangulation_data_structure_2<CGAL::Triangulation_vertex_base_with_info_2<int, CGAL::Epick> > >; AT = CGAL::Delaunay_triangulation_adaptation_traits_2<CGAL::Delaunay_triangulation_2<CGAL::Epick, CGAL::Triangulation_data_structure_2<CGAL::Triangulation_vertex_base_with_info_2<int, CGAL::Epick> > > >; AP = CGAL::Delaunay_triangulation_caching_degeneracy_removal_policy_2<CGAL::Delaunay_triangulation_2<CGAL::Epick, CGAL::Triangulation_data_structure_2<CGAL::Triangulation_vertex_base_with_info_2<int, CGAL::Epick> > > >; CGAL::Voronoi_diagram_2<DG, AT, AP>::Face_handle = CGAL::VoronoiDiagram_2::Internal::Handle_adaptor<CGAL::VoronoiDiagram_2::Internal::Face<CGAL::Voronoi_diagram_2<CGAL::Delaunay_triangulation_2<CGAL::Epick, CGAL::Triangulation_data_structure_2<CGAL::Triangulation_vertex_base_with_info_2<int, CGAL::Epick> > >, CGAL::Delaunay_triangulation_adaptation_traits_2<CGAL::Delaunay_triangulation_2<CGAL::Epick, CGAL::Triangulation_data_structure_2<CGAL::Triangulation_vertex_base_with_info_2<int, CGAL::Epick> > > >, CGAL::Delaunay_triangulation_caching_degeneracy_removal_policy_2<CGAL::Delaunay_triangulation_2<CGAL::Epick, CGAL::Triangulation_data_structure_2<CGAL::Triangulation_vertex_base_with_info_2<int, CGAL::Epick> > > > > > >; CGAL::Voronoi_diagram_2<DG, AT, AP>::Site_2 = CGAL::Point_2<CGAL::Epick>]
   inline Face_handle insert(const Site_2& t) {
                      ^
/usr/local/include/CGAL/Voronoi_diagram_2.h:757:22: note:   no known conversion for argument 1 from ‘boost::iterator_facade<boost::zip_iterator<boost::tuples::tuple<std::_List_iterator<CGAL::Point_2<CGAL::Epick> >, std::_List_iterator<int>, boost::tuples::null_type, boost::tuples::null_type, boost::tuples::null_type, boost::tuples::null_type, boost::tuples::null_type, boost::tuples::null_type, boost::tuples::null_type, boost::tuples::null_type> >, boost::tuples::cons<CGAL::Point_2<CGAL::Epick>&, boost::tuples::cons<int&, boost::tuples::null_type> >, boost::bidirectional_traversal_tag, boost::tuples::cons<CGAL::Point_2<CGAL::Epick>&, boost::tuples::cons<int&, boost::tuples::null_type> >, long int>::reference {aka boost::tuples::cons<CGAL::Point_2<CGAL::Epick>&, boost::tuples::cons<int&, boost::tuples::null_type> >}’ to ‘const Site_2& {aka const CGAL::Point_2<CGAL::Epick>&}’
/usr/local/include/CGAL/Voronoi_diagram_2.h:766:20: note: template<class Iterator> CGAL::Voronoi_diagram_2<DG, AT, AP>::size_type CGAL::Voronoi_diagram_2<DG, AT, AP>::insert(Iterator, Iterator) [with Iterator = Iterator; DG = CGAL::Delaunay_triangulation_2<CGAL::Epick, CGAL::Triangulation_data_structure_2<CGAL::Triangulation_vertex_base_with_info_2<int, CGAL::Epick> > >; AT = CGAL::Delaunay_triangulation_adaptation_traits_2<CGAL::Delaunay_triangulation_2<CGAL::Epick, CGAL::Triangulation_data_structure_2<CGAL::Triangulation_vertex_base_with_info_2<int, CGAL::Epick> > > >; AP = CGAL::Delaunay_triangulation_caching_degeneracy_removal_policy_2<CGAL::Delaunay_triangulation_2<CGAL::Epick, CGAL::Triangulation_data_structure_2<CGAL::Triangulation_vertex_base_with_info_2<int, CGAL::Epick> > > >]
   inline size_type insert(Iterator first, Iterator beyond) {
                    ^
/usr/local/include/CGAL/Voronoi_diagram_2.h:766:20: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
/usr/local/include/CGAL/Voronoi_diagram_2.h:769:17: note:   candidate expects 2 arguments, 1 provided
       insert(*it);
```

The error is very long because of the templates, but it seems to amount to `Voronoi_diagram_2::insert()` not knowing what to do with a `boost::zip_iterator`.

Am I missing something? What is the correct way to add a range of points with info to a CGAL Voronoi diagram?

Comment: Note that when you insert a range of points, CGAL first sorts them (Spatial_sorting package) and then inserts them one by one. If one interface is missing, you could always do the same.

Comment: If you avoid the caching policies, you could also get access to the delaunay triangulation with `dual()`, const_cast to get write access, then insert there. It would make sense to request with_info interfaces for Voronoi_diagram by filing an issue on github.